# Bluemix hyperledger output

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In Bluemix Blockchain service, where does the chaincode output go when I do

```
fmt.Printf("X: %v", len(someSlice))
```

in a deployed go chaincode?

I tried looking at the peer logs & chaincode logs on all peers, but I don't see `X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As independently executed programs, user-provided chaincodes can use any appropriate technique to create their private logs - from simple print statements to fully-annotated and level-controlled logs.

You should be able to see the logs by clicking the logs button for the hash id that is associated with the chaincode you deployed.

**Code:**

[image: testing logging]

**Response after posting chaincode:**

[image: deployed chaincode]

**Getting logs of chaincode id:**

[image: get logs]

**My print statement in the log:**

[image: actual log]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @joe for pointing me in the right direction. It seems my `fmt.Printf(..)` statements did NOT include a newline in the string, so another log entry from a different output stream overwrote my `stdout` in the logs. Remember to add a `\n` in the `fmt.Println()` statements!

This problem did force me to set up logging according to the [logging control](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/logging-control.html) section of the docs, which takes care of the newline problem.